# I have a C# console project I am working on With agetter and no setter

Tags: c#, getter-setter, getter

Okay so I am working on a project that haves a abstract `public abstract bool IsFull { get; }` this is how the school wants me to set it up. I was trying to figure out a work around that but I can't. I have a few files not sure if I want them all to post. so in my class it is inherited from a different class. so when I initiate it from the program cs class I can't get the boolean to change with a simple `IsFull = true`. I tried `IsFull.Equal(true);` but read that just a comparison attribute. I will show my code. Remember this is 100% new to me so if you asked questions why don't i do it this way the answer is I never was taught that lol.
So is there a way I can override it within the sweettooth class?

My Ninja class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IronNinja.Interfaces;

namespace IronNinja.Models
{
    abstract class Ninja
    {
        protected int calorieIntake;
        public List<IConsumable> ConsumptionHistory;
        public Ninja()
        {
            calorieIntake = 0;
            ConsumptionHistory = new List<IConsumable>();
        }
        public abstract bool IsFull { get; }
        public abstract void Consume(IConsumable item);
    }
}
```

my inherited class sweettooth

```
using IronNinja.Interfaces;

namespace IronNinja.Models
{
    class SweetTooth : Ninja
    {
        public string Name;
        public SweetTooth(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public override bool IsFull { get; }
        public override void Consume(IConsumable item)
        {

            // provide override for Consume
            int sweet = 0;
            if (calorieIntake >= 1500)
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                if (item.IsSweet)
                {
                    sweet = 10;
                }
                ConsumptionHistory.Add(item);
                calorieIntake += item.Calories + sweet;
            }
            item.GetInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly my Programs .cs file

```
using System;
using IronNinja.Models;

namespace IronNinja
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Buffet hungryJack = new Buffet();
            SweetTooth Albert = new SweetTooth("Alby");
            while (!Albert.IsFull)
            {
                Albert.Consume(hungryJack.Serve());
            }
            foreach (Food item in Albert.ConsumptionHistory)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                System.Console.WriteLine(item.GetInfo());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a backing Field. E.g., `private bool isFull = false;`, then the property will be `public override bool IsFull => this.isFull;`. Of course you set the backing field value in `if (calorieIntake >= 1500) { this.isFull = true; }`

Comment: @Jimi I am confused on what you are writing and what krusty is saying. It sounds like it is contradicting each other or I am just so new I am confused.

Comment: We are saying the same thing. The _isFull property value can be changed only internally

Comment: Okay I was so confused sorry I was like please demonstrate :) but thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, the `IsFull` property can simply provide the logic to return whether or not the SweetTooth is full:

```
public override bool IsFull => calorieIntake >= 1500;
```

And then in `SweetTooth.Consume` you would check if they are full before consuming more consumables:

```
public override void Consume(IConsumable item)
{

    // provide override for Consume
    int sweet = 0;
    if (IsFull)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (item.IsSweet)
        {
            sweet = 10;
        }
        ConsumptionHistory.Add(item);
        calorieIntake += item.Calories + sweet;
    }
    item.GetInfo();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, even though Krusty said it you're code explanation made more sense to me. Thank you all for the help :)

Comment: one question I am trying to `Console.WriteLine("Yo I am full as heck");` before the return in 
`if(ISFull) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Yo I am full as heck");
  return;
}`
but to no avail

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with that code snippet. Is it just not printing that text? If so, `IsFull` is probably just returning false

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't, by language design. You can't make your subclass "more permissive" than the parent class.
If you want to assign `IsFull` property, you have to do it into the `SweetTooth` class through the constructor. Generally if you set a property with private setter is because you want to manage its state internally and do not let the client code to handle it.

Then, change the `SweetTooth` constructor as per below:

```
public SweetTooth(string name, bool isFull)
        {
            Name = name;
            IsFull = isFull;
        }
```

The alternative is to add a private backing field, but again you can edit this only internally:

```
private bool _isFull;
public override bool IsFull => _isFull;
```

The `Equal` method compares two values. In your specific case you called `bool.Equals(bool)` overload which worked as `Albert.IsFull == true`